# MS Word 2010 won't print multiple copies of a document

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, printing

I have a Windows 7 64-bit machine with Office 2010, all the latest updates, printing to an HP m1212 LaserJet.

On this computer only, using Word, I can't get it to print more than one copy of a document at a time (usually I need to print about 30-40 copies of one document but it won't even print 2!).

Excel will print multiple copies of a document, no problem.

I have uninstalled/reinstalled the HP drivers, nothing. When I uninstall/reinstall Word, it works, but only for a little while.

Is there something I need to change in the Control Panel? Cancel updates?

#### Update:

I have installed the latest Windows 7 drivers and am running as administrator already.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried starting Word as administrator?

Comment: Try the [latest drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3965849) for Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Some [things to try](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Printing-Questions/Laserjet-1300-won-t-print-multiple-copies-of-a-single-page-using/td-p/37506/page/2):

- **Disable Mopier Mode and Job Storage**

  1. Select *Start > Control Panel > Printers*
  2. Right-click the desired printer icon and select *Properties*
  3. Select the *Device Settings* tab
  4. Find the *Mopier Mode* and *Job Storage* settings at the end of the listing
  5. Change the settings from *Enabled* to *Disabled*
  6. Apply changes

…if that doesn't work, see if you can repeat the above steps with *Printer Preferences* instead of *Properties* in step 2 above. Alternately, try:

- **Disable Advanced Printing Features**

  1. Go to the *Print* menu
  2. Click the *Properties* button in the upper right corner
  3. Go to the *Advanced* tab
  4. Under *Document Options*, disable *Advanced Printing Features*

If that doesn't work, try:

- **Disable Collation**

  1. Go to *File > Print > Collate Box*
  2. Uncheck the box

Or it could be:

- **Due to privileges**

  1. Right-click on Word
  2. Run as Administrator.

Comment: @TGS Infinity  Right-clicking on Word and running as Administrator fixed the problem. Do you have any idea why that worked, seems like a strange bug.  Also, I've had the printer for a year and it just started this.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just did the simplist: unchecked collate.  The document was a two page print on both sides of paper.  Now it works fine.  Must be a logic loop issue with trying to collate a one pc of paper document.